# Implementation of the Snake game in Pygame, with GUI

Tags: python, beginner, game, pygame, snake-game

I wrote a simple Snake game in Pygame, with GUI. It`s my first Pygame game and one of my first projects in Python. My goal with this implementation is to make it bug-free with fluid UI and as fast/minimal as possible.

This game is meant for both HUMAN and AI players, the first one receives user input and play and the second one play directly (you can have a look at the AI code on the github [repo](https://github.com/Neves4/SnakeAI)).

Can someone give me some advice on what changes do I need to follow best practices? (which includes speed improvement, better readability and reduction of the overall code)

Below is the full code and you can download the ready to run file in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vNkZJaGSwhOI3xZxIzuT8ETf0_TlJUyb).

## snake.py

### Imports, docstrings and global vars

I tried to follow the Google Style Python for all docstrings and a [common header format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523427/what-is-the-common-header-format-of-python-files)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""SnakeGame: A simple and fun exploration, meant to be used by AI algorithms.
"""

import sys # To close the window when the game is over
from os import environ, path # To center the game window the best possible
import random # Random numbers used for the food
import logging # Logging function for movements and errors
from itertools import tee # For the color gradient on snake
import pygame # This is the engine used in the game
import numpy as np

__author__ = "Victor Neves"
__license__ = "MIT"
__version__ = "1.0"
__maintainer__ = "Victor Neves"
__email__ = "victorneves478@gmail.com"
__status__ = "Production"

# Actions, options and forbidden moves
options = {'QUIT': 0, 'PLAY': 1, 'BENCHMARK': 2, 'LEADERBOARDS': 3, 'MENU': 4,
           'ADD_LEADERBOARDS': 5}
relative_actions = {'LEFT': 0, 'FORWARD': 1, 'RIGHT': 2}
actions = {'LEFT': 0, 'RIGHT': 1, 'UP': 2, 'DOWN': 3, 'IDLE': 4}
forbidden_moves = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 3), (3, 2)]

# Possible rewards in the game
rewards = {'MOVE': -0.005, 'GAME_OVER': -1, 'SCORED': 1}

# Types of point in the board
point_type = {'EMPTY': 0, 'FOOD': 1, 'BODY': 2, 'HEAD': 3, 'DANGEROUS': 4}

# Speed levels possible to human players
levels = [" EASY ", " MEDIUM ", " HARD ", " MEGA HARDCORE "]
```

### Classes

The classes are GlobalVariables, TextBlock, Snake FoodGenerator and Game.

- **GlobalVariables**: Holds all global variables, which can be changed and hosted in it's class.
- **TextBlock**: Pygame text structure, which can be a menu or normal text.
- **Snake**: The snake in the board, holds all of it's parts.
- **FoodGenerator**: Holds the food position and generate food if necessary.
- **Game**: Where all things related to the window, main loop, matches and GUI are hosted. My guess is that it's where the code can be optimized the most. There are two type of players that can call the Game, humans and AI. Some functions are meant for AI usage, like state, is_win and others for humans, like handle_input.

#### GlobalVariables

```
class GlobalVariables:
    """Global variables to be used while drawing and moving the snake game.

    Attributes
    ----------
    BOARD_SIZE: int, optional, default = 30
        The size of the board.
    BLOCK_SIZE: int, optional, default = 20
        The size in pixels of a block.
    HEAD_COLOR: tuple of 3 * int, optional, default = (42, 42, 42)
        Color of the head. Start of the body color gradient.
    TAIL_COLOR: tuple of 3 * int, optional, default = (152, 152, 152)
        Color of the tail. End of the body color gradient.
    FOOD_COLOR: tuple of 3 * int, optional, default = (200, 0, 0)
        Color of the food.
    GAME_SPEED: int, optional, default = 10
        Speed in ticks of the game. The higher the faster.
    BENCHMARK: int, optional, default = 10
        Ammount of matches to BENCHMARK and possibly go to leaderboards.
    """
    def __init__(self, BOARD_SIZE = 30, BLOCK_SIZE = 20,
                 HEAD_COLOR = (42, 42, 42), TAIL_COLOR = (152, 152, 152),
                 FOOD_COLOR = (200, 0, 0), GAME_SPEED = 10, BENCHMARK = 10):
        """Initialize all global variables. Can be updated with argument_handler.
        """
        self.BOARD_SIZE = BOARD_SIZE
        self.BLOCK_SIZE = BLOCK_SIZE
        self.HEAD_COLOR = HEAD_COLOR
        self.TAIL_COLOR = TAIL_COLOR
        self.FOOD_COLOR = FOOD_COLOR
        self.GAME_SPEED = GAME_SPEED
        self.BENCHMARK = BENCHMARK

        if self.BOARD_SIZE > 50: # Warn the user about performance
            logger.warning('WARNING: BOARD IS TOO BIG, IT MAY RUN SLOWER.')
```

#### TextBlock

```
class TextBlock:
    """Block of text class, used by pygame. Can be used to both text and menu.

    Attributes:
    ----------
    text: string
        The text to be displayed.
    pos: tuple of 2 * int
        Color of the tail. End of the body color gradient.
    screen: pygame window object
        The screen where the text is drawn.
    scale: int, optional, default = 1 / 12
        Adaptive scale to resize if the board size changes.
    type: string, optional, default = "text"
        Assert whether the BlockText is a text or menu option.
    """
    def __init__(self, text, pos, screen, scale = (1 / 12), type = "text"):
        """Initialize, set position of the rectangle and render the text block."""
        self.type = type
        self.hovered = False
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.screen = screen
        self.scale = scale
        self.set_rect()
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        """Set what to render and blit on the pygame screen."""
        self.set_rend()
        self.screen.blit(self.rend, self.rect)

    def set_rend(self):
        """Set what to render (font, colors, sizes)"""
        font = pygame.font.Font(resource_path("resources/fonts/freesansbold.ttf"),
                                int((var.BOARD_SIZE * var.BLOCK_SIZE) * self.scale))
        self.rend = font.render(self.text, True, self.get_color(),
                                self.get_background())

    def get_color(self):
        """Get color to render for text and menu (hovered or not).

        Return
        ----------
        color: tuple of 3 * int
            The color that will be rendered for the text block.
        """
        color = pygame.Color(42, 42, 42)

        if self.type == "menu":
            if self.hovered:
                pass
            else:
                color = pygame.Color(152, 152, 152)

        return color

    def get_background(self):
        """Get background color to render for text (hovered or not) and menu.

        Return
        ----------
        color: tuple of 3 * int
            The color that will be rendered for the background of the text block.
        """
        color = None

        if self.type == "menu":
            if self.hovered:
                color = pygame.Color(152, 152, 152)

        return color

    def set_rect(self):
        """Set the rectangle and it's position to draw on the screen."""
        self.set_rend()
        self.rect = self.rend.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.pos
```

#### Snake

```
class Snake:
    """Player (snake) class which initializes head, body and board.

    The body attribute represents a list of positions of the body, which are in-
    cremented when moving/eating on the position [0]. The orientation represents
    where the snake is looking at (head) and collisions happen when any element
    is superposed with the head.

    Attributes
    ----------
    head: list of 2 * int, default = [BOARD_SIZE / 4, BOARD_SIZE / 4]
        The head of the snake, located according to the board size.
    body: list of lists of 2 * int
        Starts with 3 parts and grows when food is eaten.
    previous_action: int, default = 1
        Last action which the snake took.
    length: int, default = 3
        Variable length of the snake, can increase when food is eaten.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Inits Snake with 3 body parts (one is the head) and pointing right"""
        self.head = [int(var.BOARD_SIZE / 4), int(var.BOARD_SIZE / 4)]
        self.body = [[self.head[0], self.head[1]],
                     [self.head[0] - 1, self.head[1]],
                     [self.head[0] - 2, self.head[1]]]
        self.previous_action = 1
        self.length = 3

    def move(self, action, food_pos):
        """According to orientation, move 1 block. If the head is not positioned
        on food, pop a body part. Else, return without popping.

        Return
        ----------
        ate_food: boolean
            Flag which represents whether the snake ate or not food.
        """
        ate_food = False

        if action == actions['IDLE']\
            or (action, self.previous_action) in forbidden_moves:
            action = self.previous_action
        else:
            self.previous_action = action

        if action == actions['LEFT']:
            self.head[0] -= 1
        elif action == actions['RIGHT']:
            self.head[0] += 1
        elif action == actions['UP']:
            self.head[1] -= 1
        elif action == actions['DOWN']:
            self.head[1] += 1

        self.body.insert(0, list(self.head))

        if self.head == food_pos:
            logger.info('EVENT: FOOD EATEN')
            self.length = len(self.body)

            ate_food = True
        else:
            self.body.pop()

        return ate_food
```

#### FoodGenerator

```
class FoodGenerator:
    """Generate and keep track of food.

    Attributes
    ----------
    pos:
        Current position of food.
    is_food_on_screen:
        Flag for existence of food.
    """
    def __init__(self, body):
        """Initialize a food piece and set existence flag."""
        self.is_food_on_screen = False
        self.pos = self.generate_food(body)

    def generate_food(self, body):
        """Generate food and verify if it's on a valid place.

        Return
        ----------
        pos: tuple of 2 * int
            Position of the food that was generated. It can't be in the body.
        """
        if not self.is_food_on_screen:
            while True:
                food = [int((var.BOARD_SIZE - 1) * random.random()),
                        int((var.BOARD_SIZE - 1) * random.random())]

                if food in body:
                    continue
                else:
                    self.pos = food
                    break

            logger.info('EVENT: FOOD APPEARED')
            self.is_food_on_screen = True

        return self.pos
```

#### Game

```
class Game:
    """Hold the game window and functions.

    Attributes
    ----------
    window: pygame display
        Pygame window to show the game.
    fps: pygame time clock
        Define Clock and ticks in which the game will be displayed.
    snake: object
        The actual snake who is going to be played.
    food_generator: object
        Generator of food which responds to the snake.
    food_pos: tuple of 2 * int
        Position of the food on the board.
    game_over: boolean
        Flag for game_over.
    player: string
        Define if human or robots are playing the game.
    board_size: int, optional, default = 30
        The size of the board.
    local_state: boolean, optional, default = False
        Whether to use or not game expertise (used mostly by robots players).
    relative_pos: boolean, optional, default = False
        Whether to use or not relative position of the snake head. Instead of
        actions, use relative_actions.
    screen_rect: tuple of 2 * int
        The screen rectangle, used to draw relatively positioned blocks.
    """
    def __init__(self, player, board_size = 30, local_state = False, relative_pos = False):
        """Initialize window, fps and score. Change nb_actions if relative_pos"""
        var.BOARD_SIZE = board_size
        self.local_state = local_state
        self.relative_pos = relative_pos
        self.player = player

        if player == "ROBOT":
            if self.relative_pos:
                self.nb_actions = 3
            else:
                self.nb_actions = 5

            self.reset_game()

    def reset_game(self):
        """Reset the game environment."""
        self.step = 0
        self.snake = Snake()
        self.food_generator = FoodGenerator(self.snake.body)
        self.food_pos = self.food_generator.pos
        self.scored = False
        self.game_over = False

    def create_window(self):
        """Create a pygame display with BOARD_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE dimension."""
        pygame.init()

        flags = pygame.DOUBLEBUF
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((var.BOARD_SIZE * var.BLOCK_SIZE,\
                                               var.BOARD_SIZE * var.BLOCK_SIZE),
                                               flags)
        self.window.set_alpha(None)
        self.screen_rect = self.window.get_rect()
        self.fps = pygame.time.Clock()

    def menu(self):
        """Main menu of the game.

        Return
        ----------
        selected_option: int
            The selected option in the main loop.
        """
        pygame.display.set_caption("SNAKE GAME  | PLAY NOW!")

        img = pygame.image.load(resource_path("resources/images/snake_logo.png"))
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (var.BOARD_SIZE * var.BLOCK_SIZE, int(var.BOARD_SIZE * var.BLOCK_SIZE / 3)))

        img_rect = img.get_rect()
        img_rect.center = self.screen_rect.center

        menu_options = [TextBlock(' PLAY GAME ', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                  4 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                  self.window, (1 / 12), "menu"),
                        TextBlock(' BENCHMARK ', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                  6 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                  self.window, (1 / 12), "menu"),
                        TextBlock(' LEADERBOARDS ', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                     8 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                     self.window, (1 / 12), "menu"),
                        TextBlock(' QUIT ', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                             10 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                             self.window, (1 / 12), "menu")]
        selected = False
        selected_option = None

        while not selected:
            pygame.event.pump()
            ev = pygame.event.get()

            self.window.fill(pygame.Color(225, 225, 225))

            for option in menu_options:
                option.draw()

                if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    option.hovered = True

                    if option == menu_options[0]:
                        for event in ev:
                            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                selected_option = options['PLAY']
                    elif option == menu_options[1]:
                        for event in ev:
                            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                selected_option = options['BENCHMARK']
                    elif option == menu_options[2]:
                        for event in ev:
                            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                selected_option = options['LEADERBOARDS']
                    elif option == menu_options[3]:
                        for event in ev:
                            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                selected_option = options['QUIT']
                else:
                    option.hovered = False

            if selected_option is not None:
                selected = True

            self.window.blit(img, img_rect.bottomleft)
            pygame.display.update()

        return selected_option

    def start_match(self):
        """Create some wait time before the actual drawing of the game."""
        for i in range(3):
            time = str(3 - i)
            self.window.fill(pygame.Color(225, 225, 225))

            # Game starts in 3, 2, 1
            text = [TextBlock('Game starts in', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                 4 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                 self.window, (1 / 10), "text"),
                    TextBlock(time, (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                 12 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                 self.window, (1 / 1.5), "text")]

            for text_block in text:
                text_block.draw()

            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.display.set_caption("SNAKE GAME  |  Game starts in "
                                       + time + " second(s) ...")

            pygame.time.wait(1000)

        logger.info('EVENT: GAME START')

    def start(self):
        """Use menu to select the option/game mode."""
        opt = self.menu()
        running = True

        while running:
            if opt == options['QUIT']:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif opt == options['PLAY']:
                var.GAME_SPEED = self.select_speed()
                self.reset_game()
                self.start_match()
                score = self.single_player()
                opt = self.over(score)
            elif opt == options['BENCHMARK']:
                var.GAME_SPEED = self.select_speed()
                score = []

                for i in range(var.BENCHMARK):
                    self.reset_game()
                    self.start_match()
                    score.append(self.single_player())

                opt = self.over(score)
            elif opt == options['LEADERBOARDS']:
                pass
            elif opt == options['ADD_LEADERBOARDS']:
                pass
            elif opt == options['MENU']:
                opt = self.menu()

    def over(self, score):
        """If collision with wall or body, end the game and open options.

        Return
        ----------
        selected_option: int
            The selected option in the main loop.
        """
        menu_options = [None] * 5
        menu_options[0] = TextBlock(' PLAY AGAIN ', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                     4 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                     self.window, (1 / 15), "menu")
        menu_options[1] = TextBlock(' GO TO MENU ', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                     6 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                     self.window, (1 / 15), "menu")
        menu_options[3] = TextBlock(' QUIT ', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                               10 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                               self.window, (1 / 15), "menu")

        if isinstance(score, int):
            text_score = 'SCORE: ' + str(score)
        else:
            text_score = 'MEAN SCORE: ' + str(sum(score) / var.BENCHMARK)
            menu_options[2] = TextBlock(' ADD TO LEADERBOARDS ', (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                                  8 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                                  self.window, (1 / 15), "menu")

        pygame.display.set_caption("SNAKE GAME  | " + text_score
                                   + "  |  GAME OVER...")
        logger.info('EVENT: GAME OVER | FINAL ' + text_score)
        menu_options[4] = TextBlock(text_score, (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                                 15 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                                 self.window, (1 / 10), "text")
        selected = False
        selected_option = None

        while not selected:
            pygame.event.pump()
            ev = pygame.event.get()

            # Game over screen
            self.window.fill(pygame.Color(225, 225, 225))

            for option in menu_options:
                if option is not None:
                    option.draw()

                    if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                        option.hovered = True

                        if option == menu_options[0]:
                            for event in ev:
                                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                    selected_option = options['PLAY']
                        elif option == menu_options[1]:
                            for event in ev:
                                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                    selected_option = options['MENU']
                        elif option == menu_options[2]:
                            for event in ev:
                                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                    selected_option = options['ADD_LEADERBOARDS']
                        elif option == menu_options[3]:
                            for event in ev:
                                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                    pygame.quit()
                                    sys.exit()
                    else:
                        option.hovered = False

            if selected_option is not None:
                selected = True

            pygame.display.update()

        return selected_option

    def select_speed(self):
        """Speed menu, right before calling start_match.

        Return
        ----------
        speed: int
            The selected speed in the main loop.
        """
        menu_options = [TextBlock(levels[0], (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                              4 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                              self.window, (1 / 10), "menu"),
                        TextBlock(levels[1], (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                              8 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                              self.window, (1 / 10), "menu"),
                        TextBlock(levels[2], (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                              12 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                              self.window, (1 / 10), "menu"),
                        TextBlock(levels[3], (self.screen_rect.centerx,
                                              16 * self.screen_rect.centery / 10),
                                              self.window, (1 / 10), "menu")]
        selected = False
        speed = None

        while not selected:
            pygame.event.pump()
            ev = pygame.event.get()

            # Game over screen
            self.window.fill(pygame.Color(225, 225, 225))

            for option in menu_options:
                if option is not None:
                    option.draw()

                    if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                        option.hovered = True

                        if option == menu_options[0]:
                            for event in ev:
                                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                    speed = 10
                        elif option == menu_options[1]:
                            for event in ev:
                                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                    speed = 20
                        elif option == menu_options[2]:
                            for event in ev:
                                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                    speed = 30
                        elif option == menu_options[3]:
                            for event in ev:
                                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                                    speed = 45
                    else:
                        option.hovered = False

            if speed is not None:
                selected = True

            pygame.display.update()

        return speed

    def single_player(self):
        """Game loop for single_player (HUMANS).

        Return
        ----------
        score: int
            The final score for the match (discounted of initial length).
        """
        # The main loop, it pump key_presses and update the board every tick.
        previous_size = self.snake.length # Initial size of the snake
        current_size = previous_size # Initial size
        color_list = self.gradient([(42, 42, 42), (152, 152, 152)],\
                                   previous_size)

        # Main loop, where the snake keeps going each tick. It generate food,
        # check collisions and draw.
        while not self.game_over:
            action = self.handle_input()
            self.game_over = self.play(action)
            self.draw(color_list)
            current_size = self.snake.length # Update the body size

            if current_size > previous_size:
                color_list = self.gradient([(42, 42, 42), (152, 152, 152)],\
                                           current_size)

                previous_size = current_size

        score = current_size - 3

        return score

    def check_collision(self):
        """Check wether any collisions happened with the wall or body.

        Return
        ----------
        collided: boolean
            Whether the snake collided or not.
        """
        collided = False

        if self.snake.head[0] > (var.BOARD_SIZE - 1) or self.snake.head[0] < 0:
            logger.info('EVENT: WALL COLLISION')
            collided = True
        elif self.snake.head[1] > (var.BOARD_SIZE - 1) or self.snake.head[1] < 0:
            logger.info('EVENT: WALL COLLISION')
            collided = True
        elif self.snake.head in self.snake.body[1:]:
            logger.info('EVENT: BODY COLLISION')
            collided = True

        return collided

    def is_won(self):
        """Verify if the score is greater than 0.

        Return
        ----------
        won: boolean
            Whether the score is greater than 0.
        """
        return self.snake.length > 3

    def generate_food(self):
        """Generate new food if needed.

        Return
        ----------
        food_pos: tuple of 2 * int
            Current position of the food.
        """
        food_pos = self.food_generator.generate_food(self.snake.body)

        return food_pos

    def handle_input(self):
        """After getting current pressed keys, handle important cases.

        Return
        ----------
        action: int
            Handle human input to assess the next action.
        """
        pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.QUIT, pygame.KEYDOWN])
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        pygame.event.pump()
        action = self.snake.previous_action

        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE] or keys[pygame.K_q]:
            logger.info('ACTION: KEY PRESSED: ESCAPE or Q')
            self.over(self.snake.length - 3)
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            logger.info('ACTION: KEY PRESSED: LEFT')
            action = actions['LEFT']
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            logger.info('ACTION: KEY PRESSED: RIGHT')
            action = actions['RIGHT']
        elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            logger.info('ACTION: KEY PRESSED: UP')
            action = actions['UP']
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            logger.info('ACTION: KEY PRESSED: DOWN')
            action = actions['DOWN']

        return action

    def eval_local_safety(self, canvas, body):
        """Evaluate the safety of the head's possible next movements.

        Return
        ----------
        canvas: np.array of size BOARD_SIZE**2
            After using game expertise, change canvas values to DANGEROUS if true.
        """
        if (body[0][0] + 1) > (var.BOARD_SIZE - 1)\
            or ([body[0][0] + 1, body[0][1]]) in body[1:]:
            canvas[var.BOARD_SIZE - 1, 0] = point_type['DANGEROUS']
        if (body[0][0] - 1) < 0 or ([body[0][0] - 1, body[0][1]]) in body[1:]:
            canvas[var.BOARD_SIZE - 1, 1] = point_type['DANGEROUS']
        if (body[0][1] - 1) < 0 or ([body[0][0], body[0][1] - 1]) in body[1:]:
            canvas[var.BOARD_SIZE - 1, 2] = point_type['DANGEROUS']
        if (body[0][1] + 1) > (var.BOARD_SIZE - 1)\
            or ([body[0][0], body[0][1] + 1]) in body[1:]:
            canvas[var.BOARD_SIZE - 1, 3] = point_type['DANGEROUS']

        return canvas

    def state(self):
        """Create a matrix of the current state of the game.

        Return
        ----------
        canvas: np.array of size BOARD_SIZE**2
            Return the current state of the game in a matrix.
        """
        canvas = np.zeros((var.BOARD_SIZE, var.BOARD_SIZE))

        if self.game_over:
            pass
        else:
            body = self.snake.body

            for part in body:
                canvas[part[0], part[1]] = point_type['BODY']

            canvas[body[0][0], body[0][1]] = point_type['HEAD']

            if self.local_state:
                canvas = self.eval_local_safety(canvas, body)

            canvas[self.food_pos[0], self.food_pos[1]] = point_type['FOOD']

        return canvas

    def relative_to_absolute(self, action):
        """Translate relative actions to absolute.

        Return
        ----------
        action: int
            Translated action from relative to absolute.
        """
        if action == relative_actions['FORWARD']:
            action = self.snake.previous_action
        elif action == relative_actions['LEFT']:
            if self.snake.previous_action == actions['LEFT']:
                action = actions['DOWN']
            elif self.snake.previous_action == actions['RIGHT']:
                action = actions['UP']
            elif self.snake.previous_action == actions['UP']:
                action = actions['LEFT']
            else:
                action = actions['RIGHT']
        else:
            if self.snake.previous_action == actions['LEFT']:
                action = actions['UP']
            elif self.snake.previous_action == actions['RIGHT']:
                action = actions['DOWN']
            elif self.snake.previous_action == actions['UP']:
                action = actions['RIGHT']
            else:
                action = actions['LEFT']

        return action

    def play(self, action):
        """Move the snake to the direction, eat and check collision."""
        self.scored = False
        self.step += 1
        self.food_pos = self.generate_food()

        if self.relative_pos:
            action = self.relative_to_absolute(action)

        if self.snake.move(action, self.food_pos):
            self.scored = True
            self.food_generator.is_food_on_screen = False

        if self.player == "HUMAN":
            if self.check_collision():
                return True
        elif self.check_collision() or self.step > 50 * self.snake.length:
            self.game_over = True

    def get_reward(self):
        """Return the current score. Can be used as the reward function.

        Return
        ----------
        reward: float
            Current reward of the game.
        """
        reward = rewards['MOVE']

        if self.game_over:
            reward = rewards['GAME_OVER']
        elif self.scored:
            reward = self.snake.length

        return reward

    def gradient(self, colors, steps, components = 3):
        """Function to create RGB gradients given 2 colors and steps. If
        component is changed to 4, it does the same to RGBA colors.

        Return
        ----------
        result: list of steps length of tuple of 3 * int (if RGBA, 4 * int)
            List of colors of calculated gradient from start to end.
        """
        def linear_gradient(start, finish, substeps):
            yield start

            for i in range(1, substeps):
                yield tuple([(start[j] + (float(i) / (substeps-1)) * (finish[j]\
                            - start[j])) for j in range(components)])

        def pairs(seq):
            a, b = tee(seq)
            next(b, None)

            return zip(a, b)

        result = []
        substeps = int(float(steps) / (len(colors) - 1))

        for a, b in pairs(colors):
            for c in linear_gradient(a, b, substeps):
                result.append(c)

        return result

    def draw(self, color_list):
        """Draw the game, the snake and the food using pygame."""
        self.window.fill(pygame.Color(225, 225, 225))

        for part, color in zip(self.snake.body, color_list):
            pygame.draw.rect(self.window, color, pygame.Rect(part[0] *\
                        var.BLOCK_SIZE, part[1] * var.BLOCK_SIZE, \
                        var.BLOCK_SIZE, var.BLOCK_SIZE))

        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, var.FOOD_COLOR,\
                         pygame.Rect(self.food_pos[0] * var.BLOCK_SIZE,\
                         self.food_pos[1] * var.BLOCK_SIZE, var.BLOCK_SIZE,\
                         var.BLOCK_SIZE))

        pygame.display.set_caption("SNAKE GAME  |  Score: "
                                    + str(self.snake.length - 3))
        pygame.display.update()
        self.fps.tick(var.GAME_SPEED)
```

### Support function, global variables init and **main**

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """Function to return absolute paths. Used while creating .exe file."""
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)

    return path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), relative_path)

var = GlobalVariables() # Initializing GlobalVariables
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # Setting logger
environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1' # Centering the window

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """The main function where the game will be executed."""
    # Setup basic configurations for logging in this module
    logging.basicConfig(format = '%(asctime)s %(module)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                        datefmt = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', level = logging.INFO)
    game = Game(player = "HUMAN")
    game.create_window()
    game.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it looks really good to me. One thing that stuck out to me was that you have a lot of repeated code:

```
for option in menu_options:
    option.draw()

    if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        option.hovered = True

        if option == menu_options[0]:
            for event in ev:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    selected_option = options['PLAY']
        elif option == menu_options[1]:
            for event in ev:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    selected_option = options['BENCHMARK']
        elif option == menu_options[2]:
            for event in ev:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    selected_option = options['LEADERBOARDS']
        elif option == menu_options[3]:
            for event in ev:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
```

I would shorten it to:

```
 list_options = ['PLAY', 'BENCHMARK', 'LEADERBOARDS', 'QUIT']

 for i in range(len(menu_options)):
     option = menu_options[i]
     option.draw()

     if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
         option.hovered = True

         for event in ev:
             if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                 selected_option = options[list_option[i]]
```

Personally I would also change the order so it only loops over the events once and breaking the loop once a new selected option has been found (assuming only one option can be selected at a time) to save time:

```
 mouse_up = False
 for event in ev:
      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
           mouse_up = True
           break

 list_options = ['PLAY', 'BENCHMARK', 'LEADERBOARDS', 'QUIT']     

 for i in range(len(menu_options)):
      option = menu_options[i]
      option.draw()

     if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
         option.hovered = True
         if mouse_up:
             selected_option = options[list_option[i]]
             break
```

I see quite a number of pieces of code which are re-used which could be shortened, for instance by creating one function and calling it several times, or looping over a dictionary and calling it's variables. This should result in a lot less code.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer - I hope to see more from you in future!

Comment: @Nathan, thanks a lot for the answer! With your help, I shortened the code in 25 lines with your first suggestion. By swapping mine code with yours last (the one the you break with each new selected option) I wasn't able to run the program, because the options only were drawn when 'pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP' (when I click). Can you have a look? Thanks!

Comment: @Neves4 you're right. I see the issue, I'll fix it.

Comment: @Nathan, I tried the fix and it works. But I think I'll stick to your first suggestion as it's more readable in my opinion. Thanks for the help!